# widget doesn't update from activity

Tags: android

Hello everybody I have used widget in my app and I want to update it from activity when button clicked , I wrote this code but the widget doesn't update , please help my , thanks.

code in AppWidgetProvider:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(final Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

    remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.widget);

    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    current_routine = prefs.getInt("current_routine", -1);

    dabase dabase = new dabase(context);
    String name = dabase.get_routine_name(current_routine);

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE");
    day3 = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    DateFormat df3 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String day2 = df3.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

    // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this provider
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_routine, name);
        remoteViews.setInt(R.id.widget_routine, "setPaintFlags", Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
        System.out.println(name + "maaaaaaaaaaaanas ");
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_date, day3 + " " + day2);
        Intent svcIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);
        //passing app widget id to that RemoteViews Service
        svcIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        //setting a unique Uri to the intent
        //don't know its purpose to me right now
        svcIntent.setData(Uri.parse(
                svcIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
        //setting adapter to listview of the widget
        remoteViews.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.widget_recycle,
                svcIntent);
        //setting an empty view in case of no data
        remoteViews.setEmptyView(R.id.widget_recycle, R.id.empty_view);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
    }

    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}
```

on Recive :

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            System.out.println("RRRERERER1312");
            if (ACTION_UPDATE.equals(intent.getAction())) {


                Toast.makeText(context, "Hello world from widget", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                System.out.println("RRRERERER");
                remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_date, "TTTTTTTT");

                AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(
                        new ComponentName(context, Widget.class), remoteViews);



            } else {
                super.onReceive(context, intent);

            }
        }
```

in Manifest :

```
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />

            <action android:name="com.example.UPDATE_MY_WIDGET"/>

        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
    </receiver>
```

in info:

```
<appwidget-provider 

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/widget"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget"
    android:minWidth="250dp"
    android:minHeight="205dp"
    android:previewImage="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="1800000"
    android:widgetCategory="keyguard|home_screen"
    >

</appwidget-provider>
```

in Activity :

```
> Intent intent = new Intent(this, Widget.class);
>         intent.setAction(Widget.ACTION_UPDATE);
>         int ids[] = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(
>                 getApplication()).getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(getApplication(), Widget.class));
>         intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, ids);
>         sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer here, but you don't need to override the onReceive method in your AppWidgetProvider to update the appwidget directly from your activity. I call the onUpdate method like this:

```
int[] ids = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplication()).
getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(getApplication(), MyWidget.class));
MyWidget myWidget = new MyWidget();
myWidget.onUpdate(this, AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this),ids);
```